# Is it possible to display the crash exception over all the code

Tags: android

**I know there is "try" and "catch" for specific parts of code,** that if they fail it goes in catch and you can display the crash exception. **But is there a way to do it over all the code in case of a crash?**

Recently I have posted a beta verison of an app game I made, and some users reported random crashes which never occurred on my device, I really want to know what causes those crashes but it is a problem asking each one of them to debug it and check logs. So I thought of displaying a toast with the exception when it happens, but I don't know if it is possible and if it is how to do it.

Comment: no it is not possible. You should look into one of the Crash reports framework, like Crashlytics or Hockey

Comment: @Blackbelt I'm not allowed to use frameworks sadly, Its a school project and I'm only allowed to use android sdk and eclipse

Comment: I guess you could ask your teacher to use a crash report framework. It is not like download the library that makes everything for you

Comment: @Blackbelt could you please explain what it exactly does? lets say I download the library, it tells me right away how the app can crash, or does it show crash report when the app crashes on a phone?

Comment: it sends the crash report to the account you register and linked to your app through an id. Sdk's integration is straightforward. The reports are kind of real time. I suggest you take a quick tour on their website.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I advise you to check out "Beta by Crashlytics" and "Crashlytics": https://get.fabric.io/. Both are frameworks that are extremely easy to set up and use. You use the first one in beta stages of your app, and the other one when your app is live.

Comment: I'm not allowed to use frameworks sadly, Its a school project and I'm only allowed to use android sdk and eclipse. Unless It wont affect my code and I could remove it later on, could you maybe explain a bit what it does and how I use it because I don't really understand

Answer (score 1):

There is a great deal of difference between could and should. For instance,

```
public static void main(String args[]){
    try{


    } catch (Exception e){


    }
}
```

will compile. It will accept any exception heading its way. However, you should not do this. Exceptions are good for programming since they let you know where you went wrong and how to correct it. You should work on correctly testing your code as opposed to finding out ways to make sure what you wrote doesn't tell you its broken. I remember working on this and finding it very frustrating when I was beginning. Believe me it is better this way. I hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks, well I agree and aware that doing it all over the code is wrong and shouldn't be done, but if its just to check why the app crashes it should be okay, right? I wasn't aware I could do that, but I'll still try the framework thing first. Thanks

Comment: Great. The main point you should know is the hierarchy of Exceptions. You can accept Exception as an input as opposed to anything specific.